# change color from CGPoint line in a subclass of uiview

Tags: swift, uiview, subclass, cgpoint, uigraphicscontext

My code is trying to change the color of the line from red to blue when the func dizzy in class View Controller is called. The problem is I dont know how to do it from class view controller. I can do it in class Canvas but I need to control it from func dizzy becuase it serves as a button in class viewController.I don't care if I have to create a func in canvas func and then call it from viewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var canvas = Canvas()
@objc func dizzy() {

}}



    class Canvas: UIView {

// public function
func undo() {
    _ = lines.popLast()
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

func clear() {
    lines.removeAll()
    setNeedsDisplay()
}




var lines = [[CGPoint]]()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(5)
    context.setLineCap(.butt)

    lines.forEach { (line) in
        for (i, p) in line.enumerated() {
            if i == 0 {
                context.move(to: p)
            } else {
                context.addLine(to: p)
            }
        }
    }

    context.strokePath()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    lines.append([CGPoint]())
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
    guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
    lastLine.append(point)
    lines.append(lastLine)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property called `strokeColor` to your `Canvas`:

```
class Canvas : UIView {
    var strokeColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```

Use `strokeColor` in `draw(rect:)`:

```
context.setStrokeColor(strokeColor.cgColor)
```

Then in `dizzy()` set the canvas' `strokeColor` to `.blue`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var canvas = Canvas()

    @objc func dizzy() {
        canvas.strokeColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Any time you set the `strokeColor` of the `Canvas`, it will trigger a redraw by calling `self.setNeedsDisplay()` in its `didSet` property observer.  The new call to `draw(rect:)` will use the new color to redraw the view.

Comment: Can you look at another question I asked? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584028/color-of-cgpoint-changes-all-lines-and-should-only-change-new-lines